# что не так? Почему происходит "зацикливание"?

Tags: javascript

```
function resolve(array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]%2 === 0){
            var tempEl = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = array[i];
            array[i] = tempEl;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
resolve([2,3,4,5,57,8,7]);
```

Comment: вообще пошаговая отладка тут помогла бы

Comment: добавь описание что должен делать данный код

Comment: наверно массив четных чисел выводить или нечетных

Comment: @stackanon, не тут какой-то обмен идет если число четное, похоже на какую-то сортировку, но какую непонятно :)

Comment: @Grundy - сгруппировать нечетные и четные числа?

Comment: @Igor, ну вообще непонятно, сейчас тут просто берется четное число и протаскивается до конца массива и даже дальше :)

Comment: Если Вы пытаетесь сгруппировать чётные и нечётные числа, то юзайте уже существующее решение - `sort`: `[2,3,4,5,57,8,7].sort(e => e % 2 === 0 ? -1 : 1); // [2, 4, 8, 7, 57, 5, 3]`.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема данного кода в том, что найдя одно четное число - оно будет бесконечно продвигаться в конец массива.

Почему бесконечно?

Потому что когда четное число является последним элементом в массиве, выполняя код

```
var tempEl = array[i+1];
array[i+1] = array[i];
array[i] = tempEl;
```

в массив добавляется еще один элемент `i+1` со значением *undefined*, и четное число меняется с ним местами и опять оказывается в конце и на следующей итерации все повторяется.

Answer (score 1):

видимо проблема в этой инструкции

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

Сделайте так

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++)
```